# How to compute value of this derivative at x=0

Tags: calculus, soft-question, self-learning

This might sound like a pretty basic thing but I cannot figure this out.

\begin{align}
q(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=&\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
\frac{dq(x)}{dx} = &\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}
\end{align}

But what is the value of $\frac{dq(x)}{dx}$ at $x=0$?

I did plot at wolframalpha.com but dont know how to make an argument that goes with it.

**Separate functions**
[image]

**Composite function**
[image]

Comment: To begin with, your original function isn't even defined at $x=0$, so you will have to add the value in. Fortunately the limit exists and is $1$,  so you can define it that way and get a continuous function.

Comment: $\frac{dq}{dx}$ does not exist at $x=0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{dq}{dx}$ exists.

Comment: You can compute the above limit by squeezing $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$.

Comment: @  Alan....can you elaborate "you will have to add value in". Is it some kind of standard procedure for such function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any even function $f$ that is differentiable at $x=0$ must have $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: But thats's the question. one can establish whether function is even or odd but how do I establish that its differentiable at $x=0$. Without this I cannot say that $f'(0) = 0$

Comment: The question asks how to compute the value of the derivative not existence. However, applying L'Hôpital's rule twice to ${f(x)-f(0) \over x}$ will show that the limit exists (and is zero).

Comment: Thank you for providing additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate the expression

$$\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$$

you can either use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) or the Taylor's expansion of cosine and sine at $x=0$. These give you
$$\frac{x\left(1+O(x^2)\right)-x+o(x^2)}{x^2} = \frac{o(x^2)}{x^2}=0$$